# jQuery redirect to div class name page (IframeTracker.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I using IframeTracker jQuery script, what alert when clicked an iframe element with the iframe class id. I want to redirect to page.php?id=(div_class) when clicked. I have this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    // Other iframes (wrapped with .iframetrack)
    $('.iframetrack iframe').iframeTracker({
        blurCallback: function(){

            $('<div class="alert alert-info">').html('Click on iframe : #' + this._overId).appendTo('#consoleDebug').delay(3000).fadeOut();

            window.setTimeout(function() {
             window.location.href = 'page.php?id=' + this._overId;
            }, 4000);

        },
        overCallback: function(element){
            this._overId = $(element).parents('.iframetrack').attr('id'); // Saving the iframe wrapper id
        },
        outCallback: function(element){
            this._overId = null; // Reset hover iframe wrapper id
        },
        _overId: null
    });

});
```

It redirect but without div class name to page.php?id=undefined
I think the "this._overId" is the class name of div but the don't works.

How can I use the clicked div class name in redirect id? (page.php?id=(clicked_div_class))

Answer (score 0):

how about:

```
$("div").click(
    function(){
    var id=this.className;
    window.location.href = 'page.php?id=' + id;
})
```

Comment: No, It's not sensitive to iframe